# Get entries that aren't related to current user

Tags: relations, current-user, exclude

I am trying to get all the entries that don't related to the current user via a user field.

I have used the following code to fetch all the entries that do related to the current user

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('movementCoursesEntries').level(1).relatedTo({
   targetElement: currentUser,
   field: 'permittedUsers'
}).find() %}
```

When I try to exclude these entries from the rest of the entries in the structure, I get nothing

```
{% set unrelated = craft.entries.section('movementCoursesEntries').level(1)|without(entries) %}

{% for entry in unrelated %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea how to filter those entries properly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('movementCoursesEntries').level(1).relatedTo({
   targetElement: currentUser,
   field: 'permittedUsers'
}).ids() | join(', not ') %}

{% set unrelated = craft.entries.section('movementCoursesEntries').level(1).id('and, not '~entries).all() %}

{% for entry in unrelated %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: @LessandMoreCollective Glad to help you!